# Change color of text based on value only returns green

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I have this c# script that is changing the color of the text based on the value of TWA. While it works mostly, it doesn't change if the

`TWA value is >=85 (where it should be yellow) and >= 90 (where it should be red)`.

How to fix this?

Here is the script:

```
protected System.Drawing.Color GetColorForLabel(string text)
{
    int theTWAValue;
    if (text != null && int.TryParse(text, out theTWAValue) && theTWAValue >= 0)
    {
        return (theTWAValue < 90) ? System.Drawing.Color.Yellow : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    return System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Additional information:

The listview with the TWA value is not going to be shown until the user selects certain job code from the drop down list and all the data values are coming from an `access database`

Edit2: Even after `debugging` I still haven't found a solution, some assistance to why my if statement is failing would be great

Edit 3: Here is the rest of the code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Plant] FROM [PLANT]">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Plant" DataValueField="Plant" Height="85px" Width="393px">
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Plant], [Group No#] AS column1, [Group] FROM [Temp Table that contains TWA values] WHERE ([Plant] = ?)">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Plant" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Group" DataValueField="column1" Height="30px" Width="394px">
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 (2013-06-24)ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Plant], [Group No#] AS column1, [Group], [Job Code] AS Job_Code, [Job Function] AS Job_Function, [Job Classification] AS Job_Classification FROM [Temp Table that contains TWA values] WHERE (([Plant] = ?) AND ([Group No#] = ?))">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Plant" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="column1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Job_Classification" DataValueField="Job_Classification" Height="17px" Width="384px">
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:ListView id="YourListView" OnLoad="YourListView_Load" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <span style="">Plant:
          <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
          <br />
          column1:
          <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
          <br />
          Group:
          <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
          <br />
          Job_Code:
          <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
          <br />
          Job_Classification:
          <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />
          <br />
          Job_Function:
          <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
          <br />
          Job_Description:
          <asp:Label id="Job_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Description") %>' />
          <br />
          TWA:
          <asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>'  ForeColor='<%# GetColorForLabel( Eval("TWA") as string ) %>'/>
          <br />
          <br />
          </span>
      </ItemTemplate>

      </asp:ListView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:2007  SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ( 2013-06-24)ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Plant], [Group No#] AS column1, [Group], [Job Code] AS Job_Code, [Job Classification] AS Job_Classification, [Job Function] AS Job_Function, [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [TWA] FROM [Temp Table that contains TWA values] WHERE (([Plant] = ?) AND ([Group No#] = ?) AND ([Job Classification] = ?))">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Plant" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="column1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Job_Classification" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I still haven't been able to fix the error, so input is still highly valuable

Comment: i imagine your if statement is failing, otherwise you'd never get green

Comment: is the ')' after the 90 a typo? if not that's your problem.

Comment: Debug and see what happens when you step through it.

Comment: @SOfanatic - pretty sure that's OK.

Comment: Come on. Format the question, have matching {}, and Debug the output from the TryParse.

Comment: "Only returns green" is not a useful title for anyone searching for this issue. Can you improve it?

Comment: Obviously the IF-statement falls through. Figure it out by debugging the code. It should be pretty obvious when you do (and no, I don't know, but this code is simple, debugging this to figure out why the IF-statement falls through should be short work)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have tried debugging it and have no success that is why I am asking it on stackoverflow....

Comment: @friendo9876 For one of the values that you think should be yellow or red, what is the value of `text`?

Comment: The values where 89 and 92

Comment: I copied your method exactly. When I pass in "89", I get yellow back. When I pass "92", I get red back. Are you sure you're passing the correct values? Did you debug and see what the values actually were in the method? Are there spaces before or after the value?

Comment: This is what I get in my output <span id="YourListView_TWALabel_0" style="color:Green;"> 85,522 </span>

Comment: @friendo9876 more than likely there's white space you're not showing, or the object you're looking at in the debugger isn't a `string`.  Is `" 85,522"` your `text` string?  That would explain it.  (For one thing commas aren't allowed, for another leading spaces...)

Answer (score 1):

*text* is either *null* or *int.TryParse* fails due to input that can't be converted.

```
int theTWAValue;
string text = "95";
if (text != null && int.TryParse(text, out theTWAValue) && theTWAValue >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine((theTWAValue < 90) ? "System.Drawing.Color.Yellow" : "System.Drawing.Color.Red");
}
```

Prints: System.Drawing.Color.Red

Comment: Values are coming from a database, i am not hard coding the TWA values

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the logic works when _text_ is valid so the problem is most likely that _int.TryParse_ fails.

Comment: @friendo9876 +1 The problem isn't in this code.  It can successfully return all 3 colors.  The problem is either the returned colors aren't being used or, more likely, that the input from the access database is not a properly formatted number string.  A debugger should be showing strings in `text` that aren't correct numbers.

Comment: @ebyrob You might be correct as i just checked the access database and TWA values are numbers not short text

Comment: @ebyrob I have add the rest of my code, if you can take a look at and be able to fix the if statement that would be excellent

Comment: @friendo9876 So, `TWALabel` is getting it's text and color by `Eval("TWA")`.  I didn't think you could mix and match Eval syntax with plain old C# code.  when you set a breakpoint inside `GetColorForLabel()` does it actually get hit?  If so, what's in `text`?  (Please copy/paste from a Visual Studio Watch)

Answer (score 0):

Change the decision:

```
return (theTWAValue < 90) ? System.Drawing.Color.Yellow : System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

to this:

```
return (theTWAValue < 85) ? Color.Green :
    (theTWAValue < 90) ? Color.Yellow :
    Color.Red;
```

See, what's happening is if it parses you're not evaluating all three scenarios. It's okay to have the default return `Color.Green`, so leave that there, but if it parses and it's `>= 0` then you need to evaluate all three conditions.

#### EDIT

As stated by Kevin DeVoe, in this case, since you're **always** getting `Green`, it appears the value is **never** actually parsing to an `int`. The code inside the `if` was still wrong because it didn't have all three scenarios, but your root problem is the fact that it's not parsing - ever.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case here because he's only getting green, that means it's not even getting to the evaluation.

Comment: I get this error now: CS0161: 'ASP.testing_aspx.GetColorForLabel(string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @friendo9876, sounds to me like you removed the default `return` statement.

Comment: @KevinDeVoe, very good analysis. My bad on that one. I'm going to edit the answer to indicate that and leave the code sample because the evaluation was wrong still.

Comment: I was but even when I added it every TWA value is still green

Comment: How do I fix the parsing problem?

Comment: @friendo9876, send a value that can be parsed to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in

```
if (text != null && int.TryParse(text, out theTWAValue) && theTWAValue >= 0)
```

you need to debug it and step through it to find why it's failing.  Add this before your if statement and check the console.

```
if(text == null) 
     Console.WriteLine("Text is null");
if(!int.TryParse(text, out theTWAValue)) 
     Console.WriteLine("Parse Failed");
Console.WriteLine("TWA Value: " + theTWAValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` is `null` in all cases.

Try replacing:

```
ForeColor='<%# GetColorForLabel( Eval("TWA") as string ) %>'
```

with:

```
ForeColor='<%# GetColorForLabel( "" + Eval("TWA") ) %>'
```

Or you could use `.ToString()`, but I really find it more complicated...  Accepting `object` as input to `GetColorForLabel()` would also work.

Note: You've been doing the equivalent of:

```
string s = (object)5 as string;  // always going to be null
```